# React front-end renders differently from state

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, render, setstate, react-dom

I am building a react app which creates graphs. I Use *react-d3-geaph* for this. The graph takes its data from state like this:

```
   data: {
    nodes: [
         { "id": "1", "name": "connector"},
         { "id": "2", "name": "id1"},
         { "id": "3", "name": "node"}
     ],
     links: [
         {"source": "1" , "target": "2"},
         {"source": "3" , "target": "1"}
       ]
   }
```

The rendered graph is the following:
[image]

What I am trying to achieve now, is to delete a link when the user clicks on it. react-d3-graph gives a method that returns the source and the target of the clicked link. So I have written the following function to find and delete the right link:

```
delLink(source, target) {

    var data = {...this.state.data};
    var dataArray = [...data.links];

    for(var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
      if(dataArray[i].source === source && dataArray[i].target === target) {
        console.log(i);
        dataArray.splice(i, 1);
        data.links = dataArray;
        this.setState({data: data}, function () {
          console.log(this.state.data);
        });
      }
    }
   }
```

This function achieves to find successfully the index of the state array and then delete it. While I console.log the new state I get the result I wish. For example, if I click the link from *connector* to *id1* this is the new state:

```
data: {
    nodes: [
         { "id": "1", "name": "connector"},
         { "id": "2", "name": "id1"},
         { "id": "3", "name": "node"}
     ],
     links: [
         {"source": "3" , "target": "1"}
       ]
   }
```

However, the problem is that, although the function works properly and erases the right index from the *links array*, the app renders a wrong graph with the wrong link deleted:
[image]

After some tries, I realized that whatever link I click the app will delete the **last link** from the link array.
Lastly, if I save the new graph through the app and refresh it, I get the right graph this time with a link between *node* and *connector*.

I believe it is a React issue regarding the asynchronous functionality but I can not figure out how I could solve it.

Please tell if you need any other information.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you provide an example on codesandbox?

Comment: I will with the first chance. Thank you

Comment: I'm failing to understand why the last e ample is wrong, you show a state of connect 1 to 3, and your screenshot also shows this. BTW thanks for the detailed question

Comment: The link is from 3(node) to 1(connector). However in the screenshot the link is between connector and id1. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Array::splice mutates the array in place, you want to return an entirely new array of links with the deleted one filtered out.

[array::splice mdn](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

I'm on mobile commuting now, but if you'd like I can provide an example to help illustrate.

[Edit] Oops, I see that you do copy the array first, but then you store it back in data, which is a reference to the previous state. Try spreading the previous state (and array because shallow copying) into a new data object, mutate the array there, and set state as normal.

Can you provide a codesandbox example for us to examine?

Comment: I will with the first chance. Thank you